# Unable to inspect element using xpath - Not unique

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to inspect an element on the webpage. The `Xpath` which I tried is not unique. I've attached the html code and image of the element which needs to be inspected. `"Columns"` is what I'm trying to inspect here.

Xpath which I tried = `//span[text()='Columns']`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p89R.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0Tt.png

Comment: See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6367213)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is `text node`, cause it is wrapped inside `""`. Selenium usage `xpath V1.0`, so you cannot parse that.

Now, since you've mentioned that there are duplicate text on the web page, we can **give it a try with xpath indexing :**

```
(//span[@class='l-link']/span)[1]
```

to represent the first element, you can change `[1]` to `[2]` or any other number to see if we are getting unique matching nodes.

Comment: Hello cruise , Indexing didn't help. It was a hover over , so my issue is fixed by using actions class. Thank you!